# knockoutjs: order matters in computed observable?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a computed observable that does not update due to the order of the observables in the computed observable function. Clicking on the branch does not update the computed observable on the leaf. Is this intended?

https://jsfiddle.net/acL3f1qp/9/

javascript:

```
(function() {

  function Branch(viewModel) {
    var self = this;
    self.isAllowed;
    self.isChecked = ko.observable();
    self.isChecked.subscribe(function(newValue){
        //is updating?
      null;
    });
    self.leaves = [];
    self.allowLeaves = ko.computed(function() {
      return viewModel.allowLeaves() && (!self.isAllowed || self.isChecked());
    });
  }

  function Leaf(branch) {
    var self = this;
    var isCheckedInternal = ko.observable();
    self.isAllowed;
    self.isChecked = ko.computed({
            read: function() {
            return branch.allowLeaves() && isCheckedInternal();
            },
        write: function(value) {
            isCheckedInternal(value);
        }
    });
  }

  function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var branch;
    var leaf;
    self.allowLeaves = ko.observable(true);
    self.branches = [];
    branch = new Branch(self);
    branch.isAllowed = true;
    branch.isChecked(true);
    leaf = new Leaf(branch);
    leaf.isAllowed = true;
    leaf.isChecked(true);
    branch.leaves.push(leaf);
    self.branches.push(branch);
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

})();
```

html:

```
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: allowLeaves" />
    <span>allow leaves</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="indent" data-bind="foreach: branches">
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked, visible: isAllowed" />
      <span>branch</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="indent" data-bind="foreach: leaves">
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked, visible: isAllowed" />
        <span>leaf</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
clicking on "branch" does
```

not update computed on leaf!

Comment: Your selfs are pertaining to different parts of the viewModel, so self.allowBranch is undefined where you do the test.

Comment: Some additional remarks. - Are you sure some of those arrays (`branches`, `leaves`) shouldn't be *observable* arrays? - The `isCheckedInternal` var isn't observable so changing it would never trigger a computed update, so what's the point of it (at least in this repro?). - The Leaf `isChecked` is a *readonly* computed, but you have a two-way binding in the view?

Comment: At any rate, on constructing the view model computed functions will run *once*, setting up all dependencies as other observables are called for their value. Because of short circuiting logical operators as well as early return statements the initial run might fail to set up dependencies properly. Try reordering your observable getters (e.g. start with just plainly calling them and saving their value in local variables at the start of the computed function) to see if that's your issue.

Comment: @brianlmerrit You are correct, there was an error in my example. I have since updated the example to demonstrate my issue. It appears to be due  to setting the properties of the branch after it has been instantiated.

Comment: @Jeroen I believe that short circuiting of the logical operation is the cause of the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear you found the root cause! Please consider posting your resolution as an answer and accept that, so others can easily spot it.

Comment: @Jeroen The answer is yours. Post and I will accept.

Comment: is this fiddleabove  the latest one?  Clicking on allow leaves doesn't alter branch - is that intended behaviour?#

Comment: @SeanWilmot I'd prefer you create a minimal working example, since you have the most info to create an answer that'll help others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of observables in a computed only matters as far as building [dependencies](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html);

In this computed:

```
ko.pureComputed(function(){
  return a() && b(); 
}
```

(assume `a` and `b` are observable and return either `true` or `false`)

If a returns false then `b` will not be evaluated (since the [&&](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) operator is lazy) and KO will not create a dependency on `b`, only on `a`.

This is good - any change to `b` can have no impact on the value of this computed so reevaluating would be a waste of resources.

If `a` is updated to return `true` KO will reevaluate the computed (since it does have a dependency on `a`) and in doing so will need to find out what value `b` has and will then create a dependency.

---

As for your fiddle - as far I can see your problem is that the `isChecked` observable on the branch is not linked in any way to the `allowLeaves` computed. So it doesn't get updated.

If you change you implementation of `Branch` to look more like `Leaf` with an `isCheckedInternal` like this:

```
function Branch(viewModel) {
  var self = this;
  self.isAllowed = ko.observable();
  var isCheckedInternal = ko.observable();

  self.leaves = [];
  self.allowLeaves = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function() {
      return viewModel.allowLeaves() && isCheckedInternal();
    },
    write: function(val){
      isCheckedInternal(val);
  }});
}
```

and then bind the checked to `allowLeaves` then it appears to work as expected.

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayseeare/t2gfe88g/) which is working...